# Excel VBA Copy block of cells with variable row and column number

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to select a block of cells with having the row and column number as variable. Lets start with a static one:-[image]

I already got the row count for the merged cells. Now I am trying to copy the complete block for a Use case to a new sheet (with same name as Use case).
So for example I am trying to Copy Range("C7:K11") of use case Random 1 to Worksheet Random1.

The only issue, I am encountering here is to copy this  Range with varibale row number and column number. 
However, This static code as well as code with dynamic variable is not working:-

```
shtPricing.Range(Cells(7, 3), Cells(9, 11)).Copy
xWb.Worksheets(UsecaseTrail).Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(4, 11)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Exact code:

```
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColumnCounter As Long
Dim RowCounter As Long
Dim tempUseCase As String

lColumn = xWb.Worksheets("Pricing").Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For RowCounter = 7 To 25 
    RowCount = xWb.Worksheets("Pricing").Range("B" & RowCounter).MergeArea.Rows.Count
    If RowCount > 1 Then
        If InStr(1, CStr(xWb.Worksheets("Pricing").Range("B" & RowCounter).Value), UsecaseTrail) Then 
                xWb.Worksheets("Pricing").Range(Cells(RowCounter, 3), Cells(RowCounter + RowCount - 1, lColumn)).Copy
                xWb.Worksheets(UsecaseTrail).Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(2 + RowCount - 1, lColumn)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    
            End If
        RowCounter = RowCounter + RowCount - 1 'note -1 here
    End If
Next RowCounter
```

Please note that everything is working fine. Except for the copy paste function with variable Rowcounter and columncounter value. 
It would be really helpful to get through following code only :-

```
xWb.Worksheets("Pricing").Range(Cells(RowCounter, 3), Cells(RowCounter + RowCount - 1, lColumn)).Copy
xWb.Worksheets(UsecaseTrail).Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(2 + RowCount - 1, lColumn)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Error :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
With shtPricing
    Set r1 = Range(.Cells(7, 3), .Cells(9, 11))
End With

With xWb.Worksheets(UsecaseTrail)
    Set r2 = Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(4, 11))
End With

r1.Copy
r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a tested example:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim shtPricing As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim UsecaseTrail As String
    Dim xWb As Workbook

    Set shtPricing = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set xWb = ThisWorkbook
    UsecaseTrail = "Sheet2"

    With shtPricing
        Set r1 = Range(.Cells(7, 3), .Cells(9, 11))
    End With

    With xWb.Worksheets(UsecaseTrail)
        Set r2 = Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(4, 11))
    End With

    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Please note the ***dots*** on the `Cells()`

Comment: Thanks for this.. I am trying to implement it.

Comment: @Heinreich213  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Well your solution is working. I replaced the numbers with the variable as :     `Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
                    With shtPricing
                        Set r1 = Range(.Cells(RowCounter, 3), .Cells(RowCounter + RowCount - 1, lColumn))
                    End With
                    With xWb.Worksheets(UsecaseTrail)
                        Set r2 = Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(2 + RowCount - 1, lColumn))
                    End With
                    r1.Copy
                    r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`